# How can I make thread for a method with parameter from another method

Tags: c#

I can't make a thread for this method, because it has one parameter. I see same questions like this but my methods are "separated" and if I pass the variable to it the error says that the name `text` (the argument name) doesn't exist in this current context.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread TH = new Thread(PressBind); //I cant make thread for this method
    TH.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    TH.Start();
}

private void TxBxKTB_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox objTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
    string text = objTextBox.Text;
    label2.Text = $"the bind key is {text}";
    PressBind(text);
}

void PressBind(string text)
{
    Enum.TryParse(text, out Key key1);

    Thread.Sleep(40);
    label1.Text = "ready";
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(key1))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(40);
        SendKeys.SendWait("e");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.key1)`? It should be `Keyboard.IsKeyDown(key1)`. And what if parsing is failed? Then switch to just `Parse` rather `TryParse` if you're sure the parsing will never fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PressBind` method must match the signature of [ParameterizedThreadStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart?view=netframework-4.8), which accepts parameter of type `object`. Inside the `PressBind method`, cast this parameter to string. The value is passed to the thread in [Thread.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.start?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Thread_Start_System_Object_).

Also note, that in order to update a `Label` text from the other thread, you have to use [Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.8).

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread TH = new Thread(PressBind); //I cant make thread for this method
    TH.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    TH.Start("some-text" /* here you pass the text */);
}

private void TxBxKTB_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox objTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
    string text = objTextBox.Text;
    label2.Text = $"the bind key is {text}";
    PressBind(text);
}

void PressBind(object state)
{
    string text = (string)state; // cast object parameter back to string

    // do other things...

    // must use InvokeRequired + Invoke if accessing Label 
    // created by the UI thread
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {    
       Invoke(() => label1.Text = "ready"); 
    }
    else
    {
       label1.Text = "ready"; // we're on the UI thread
    }

    // do other things...
}
```